# Build angular material component library locally with sourcemaps

Tags: angular, angular-material, onblur, onfocus

we use angular/material components such as MatRadioButton. I've recently been having trouble with the focus jumping to the wrong point on the page on what I think is a blur event. I haven't been able to figure out why it's happening. Only that when I remove the material form fields and replace them with standard html elements the issue goes away. The only problem is I lose all the underlying built in functionality of material.

I want to build materialy locally with source maps enabled so that I can put some break points in the browser and view exactly what's going on in the code with these components that's causing the focus jump.

I've cloned the library, version 14 (version we have to use right now), downloaded bazel (the tool they use to build it), and I've succesfully built it locally. But no matter what setting I change it refuses to build with the sourcemaps.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or missing? I'm hoping this is some stupid small thing that I've missed. You know...those things that someone points out and you're like "dangit lol".